# Compose: How to get IntrinsicSize.Max to work with Row with ConstraintLayout children that use fillToConstraint

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I'd like to create a scrollable `Row` where the height of each item in the `Row` is the height of the tallest item. In most cases, one would use `Modifier.height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)` on the `Row`'s `modifier`. But when the items are `ConstraintLayout`s that use `Dimension.fillToConstraints`, this undesirably stretches the height of the `Row`.

Using the test code at the bottom of this post...

**When using `TestBox` as the children, I get the desired behavior...**

[image: TestBox item1 in Row]
[image: TestBox item2 in Row]

**When I replace `TestBox` with a `TestConstraintLayout` that uses `Modifier.fillToConstraints`, I'm unable to get the same result.**

[image: TestConstraint item1 in Row]

**Test Code**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.horizontalScroll
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalConfiguration
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.Dimension

private val DEFAULT_PADDING = 16.dp
private const val LOREM_IPSUM = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent { TestScreen() }
    }
}

@Preview(backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF, showBackground = true, widthDp = 360)
@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    val itemWidth: Dp = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp - (DEFAULT_PADDING * 2)
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Intrinsic Size + ConstraintLayout",
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .padding(top = DEFAULT_PADDING, start = DEFAULT_PADDING, end = DEFAULT_PADDING)
        )
        Text(
            text = "The goal of this demo is to create a Row where every item in the Row is the same height despite the fact that they might have differing heights. We are able to achieve this when the children are Boxes, but unable to achieve this when they are ConstraintLayouts",
            fontSize = 12.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .padding(top = DEFAULT_PADDING, start = DEFAULT_PADDING, end = DEFAULT_PADDING)
        )

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                // This seems to break the TestConstraintLayout but not the TestBox
                .height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)
                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(top = DEFAULT_PADDING, start = DEFAULT_PADDING, end = DEFAULT_PADDING),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(DEFAULT_PADDING)
        ) {
            // When using TestBox, we get the desired behavior.
            // But replace TestBox with TestConstraintLayout, and the Row height gets messed up.
            // Especially when we use fillToConstraints
            TestBox(
                text = LOREM_IPSUM.substring(200),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(itemWidth)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            )
            TestBox(
                text = LOREM_IPSUM,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(itemWidth)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            )
        }

        Text(
            text = "Bottom of Screen",
            fontSize = 12.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(vertical = DEFAULT_PADDING)
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        )
    }
}

@Preview(backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF, showBackground = true, widthDp = 360)
@Composable
fun TestBox(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, text: String = LOREM_IPSUM) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .then(modifier)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(DEFAULT_PADDING)
        )
    }
}

/**
 * Note that we are using a ConstraintLayout with minimal content for the sake of simplicity to demonstrate the issue.
 * In practice, the content of the ConstraintLayout would be more complicated.
 */
@Preview(backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF, showBackground = true, widthDp = 360)
@Composable
fun TestConstraintLayout(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, text: String = LOREM_IPSUM) {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .then(modifier)
    ) {
        val (textView) = createRefs()
        Text(
            text = text,
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(textView) {
                linkTo(
                    top = parent.top, topMargin = DEFAULT_PADDING,
                    bottom = parent.bottom, bottomMargin = DEFAULT_PADDING,
                    bias = 0f,
                )
                start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = DEFAULT_PADDING)
                end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = DEFAULT_PADDING)
                // Switching this to matchParent does makes a difference.
                // But, it does NOT keep the text top-aligned.
                // Instead, it centers the text vertically, which is not a desired behavior
                // Still, even if replacing fillToConstraints with matchParent worked in this test,
                // it wouldn't be a true solution bc with complex ConstraintLayout content, we
                // might want content with fillToConstraints
                width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                height = Dimension.wrapContent
            }
        )
    }
}
```

How can I get my `ConstraintLayout` children inside my `Row` to behave the same way that my `Box` children behave (ie. height of children is height of tallest child)?

Comment: Submitted a bug report here. Please +1 it if you're having similar issues. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280100760